# Cómo chequeo un cast con ArrayList

Tags: java

tengo esto:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = (ArrayList<Integer>) list1.clone();
```

El compilador me dice que:

```
Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>'
```

Como puedo hacer eso que dice?

Muchas gracias.
Un saludo

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer en sí y qué hay en `list1`?

Comment: Hay una lista de números y quiero clonar el ArrayList<Integer> que es el list1

Answer (score 0):

Dado que `clone()` regresa `Object` y en tiempo de ejecución el tipo genérico se pierde, y para no suprimir la advertencia mejor haz:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Que tal algo tan simple como esto:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList();        
list2.addAll(list1);
```